# Login Issue in Oracle SQL Developer while connecting to connections

Tags: authentication, oracle-sqldeveloper

I see this error while trying to login in SQL Developer:

Error:

```
An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection 
(CONNECTION_ID=DH7GhF6+R+WU+8MNR0Y/Qw==)

Vendor code 17002
```